# Detect unique colors in an image visible to eye

Tags: laravel, algorithm, colors, detection, color-detection

Aoa,

I am currently working on a project and got stuck.Actually i want an algorithm to detect number of colors in an image that are visible to human eye. I used some packages over the internet but they are providing even small color changes.

**Example :**
The below provided image has two visible colors but the package I use showing 4 or more than 4 and if some package gives accurate color for this image than it shows wrong count for image having multiple colors.
[image: Example Image i used]

**Some Packages that I used**

http://www.coolphptools.com/color_extract#demo

https://github.com/brianmcdo/ImagePalette

Comment: You could interpret the colors which come back and see if they are within a threshold of other colors. In that case you could de-duplicate them to only leave you with the colors 'visible to the eye'.

Comment: well most of the packages are returning pixel count and the hex value so can you suggest how could we achieve what you said above?

Comment: Hex values consist of 6 characters. The first two are for red, the second pair is for green and the last pair is for blue. Based on those 3 colors you can determine how close each part is to the other.

Comment: This is because corners usually have anti-alised (Google that if you don't know what it is) pixels, screenshot of this effect: https://d.bouma.dev/261piOUuBI77. So the 4 is probably acurate. You could try and pixelate the image to remove those pixels and maybe only extract colors that make up more than x% of the image to get a "good" enough reading depending on your use case.

Comment: @AlexBouma yeah i know and i have tried that technique and it work fine for some of the images but get fail if we upload images with a low total pixel count and alot of colors

Comment: I think that you need a more formal definition of what a 'unique color visible to eye' is, because depending on how you define it, the result will change a *lot*

Comment: The second link you provide is easy enough to do. You just define a set of 32, or 64 or 200 colours and you map each of the colours in your image to the nearest one in your set. But that means you'll never get more than 32, or 64 or 200 colours as your answer. What are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a perfect implementation (this is going to be slow, particularly on big images), but we could do something like:

```
$resource = imagecreatefrompng("test.png");  // Load our image (use imagecreatefromjpeg if using jpeg)
$width = imagesx($resource); // Get image width
$height = imagesy($resource); // Get image height
$results = []; // Create empty array to hold our "unique" color results

$tolerance = 5; // The amount of variation allowed to consider a color the same

// Loop each pixel in the image
for($x = 0; $x < $width; $x++) {
  for($y = 0; $y < $height; $y++) {

    $add = true;
    $color_index = imagecolorat($resource, $x, $y);
    $color = imagecolorsforindex($resource, $color_index); // Get the color as an array

    // Push the first pixel into our results so we have something to start the comparison against
    if (count($results) == 0){
      $results[] = $color;
    } else {
      // Compare the current colour to our results using the tolerance
      foreach ($results as $i => &$result):
        $near_red = ($color['red'] > ($result['red'] - $tolerance)) && ($color['red'] < ($result['red'] + $tolerance));
        $near_green = ($color['green'] > ($result['green'] - $tolerance)) && ($color['green'] < ($result['green'] + $tolerance));
        $near_blue = ($color['blue'] > ($result['blue'] - $tolerance)) && ($color['blue'] < ($result['blue'] + $tolerance));

        if ($near_red && $near_green && $near_blue){
          // This colour is similar to another result
          $add = false;
        }

        if (!$add){
          break;
        }
      endforeach;

      if ($add){
        $results[] = $color;
      }
    }
  }
}

// Output the unique colors visually. You would probably just count($results) here
foreach($results as $item):
  $color = $item['red'] . "," . $item['green'] . "," . $item['blue'] . "," . "1";
  echo "<div style='width: 10px; height: 10px; background-color: rgba($color); display: inline-block;'></div>";
endforeach;
```

Using this image (which contains 8 unique colors):

[image: image 1]

and a tolerance of `75` we get the an output of the following 4 colors:

[image: 75]

With a tolerance of `10` we get the following 8 colors:

[image: 10]

As we loop each pixel in the image we get the color values in RGBA format like:

```
[
  "red"   => 255,
  "green" => 255,
  "blue"  => 255,
  "alpha" => 255,
]
```

We can then compare the current pixel to each item in our `$results` array by adding and subtracting the tolerance and checking if the current channel (red, green and blue) falls within the range:

```
$near_red = ($color['red'] > ($result['red'] - $tolerance)) && ($color['red'] < ($result['red'] + $tolerance));
```

For example, if our current pixels red value is 50 and our tolerance is 5, we would check if there is an item in our `$results` with a red value between 45 and 55. We do the same for green and blue. If all 3 channels are within the range, it means we already have a similar color in our `$results`, so we don't add the current pixel color to the `$results` array.

A greater `$tolerance` value will match against less similar colors. A `$tolerance` value of `0` will check exact match and result in far more unique colors in our `$results`.

If a similar value doesn't exist, we push the current pixel RGBA value to our `$results` array.

Once the code is finished running, the `$results` array will contain the "unique" colors. We can count the colors like so:

```
echo count($results);
```

This solution could use a lot of optimisation (it will be very slow on large images with a lot of unique colors), and I've ignored the alpha channel in this implementation (easy enough to add in if needed) but hopefully it's useful to you.

The worst case complexity of this implementation is

```
O(n2)
```

which would happen if every pixel color in the image is unique, which would cause our `$results` array to contain every previous value so each iteration would contain a nested loop of the number of pixels in the image (more or less), which for a large image would be incredibly slow.

Comment: well your code is quite good have to tweek it a little bit but working good not resulting 100% but seem quite acceptable.

Comment: It's a tricky problem since visible to human eye is a pretty ambiguous problem, but best of luck. Please share your final implementation when you find it!